# Транзакции mongodb

Tags: mongodb, transaction

В mongodb не поддерживаются транзакции в должной мере. Мне интересно, как господа обходят эту проблему? Я знаю, что это можно частично решить при помощи индексов. Но так и не разобрался как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моё решение. Если Ваш сервис не очень нагруженный, то это легко сделать. Создаётся отдельный сервис (либо же, если у Вас не предполагается масштабирование, то отдельный пакет, класс, модуль ...), который умеет в атомарные операции (т.е. внутри него зашит мьютекс). Перед каждой операцией нужно спросить этот сервис: есть ли у нас уже операция, которая затрагивает наши интересы в текущий операции. Если да, то нужно сделать отказ. Если нет, то можно продолжать, выставив, например, в ту же монгу, в отдельную коллекцию, соответствующий статус, чтобы другие операции могли узнать об этом.